# With Javascript, how to create a physical html file on the server via API?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, api, rest

I need to create an api that when receiving some parameters, physically create an .html file on my server.

I'm using node.js, vue.js, and the server is Google's Firebase.

The goal is to create html files dynamically so that they can be consulted later by users, and have the meta tags inside them, so that when sharing this html on facebook, the meta tag information appears.

Thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this when you hit your API.

```
var fs = require('fs');

var htmlContent = '<html>Whatever</html>';

fs.writeFile('/my-page.html', htmlContent, (error) => { /* handle error */ });
```